# Why PHP function doesn't work on live server?

Tags: php

I have a function in php where I check roles and permissions. I keep the roles and permissions in `$_SESSION['permissions']` when the user logs in and I control them with my `check_users_permissions` function. So I show and hide some things according to the user's role and permissions. This works perfectly on localhost but for some reason it doesn't work when I upload it to the live server. So for example, when **User X** has access to **Y**, **Y** is displayed. It works in localhost but in live server **Y** is not displayed even though the user has permissions and I also checked `$_SESSION['permissions']` values the same values are stored in `$_SESSION['permissions']` on both localhost and live server. I don't understand exactly what the problem is. Why it is not works in live server.

**Here is my class and functions:**

```
class User
{
    private $_db;
    private $_ignoreCase;

    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->_db = $db;
        $this->_ignoreCase = false;
    }

    public function setIgnoreCase($sensitive)
    {
        $this->_ignoreCase = $sensitive;
    }

    public function getIgnoreCase()
    {
        return $this->_ignoreCase;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username)
    {
        try {
            if ($this->_ignoreCase) {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT userID, userRoleID, password, email, tfaSwitch, tfaCode, username FROM users WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER(:username) AND activasionCode="Completed" ');
            } else {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT userID, userRoleID, password, email, tfaSwitch, tfaCode, username FROM users WHERE username = :username AND activasionCode="Completed" ');
            }
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
        }
    }

    public function get_user_permissions($username)
    {

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        try {

            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT roleID, permissionID, permissionName FROM roles_permissions WHERE roleID = :userRoleID");
            $stmt->execute(array(
                'userRoleID' => $row['userRoleID']
            ));

            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
        }
    }

    public function isValidUsername($username)
    {

        if (strlen($username) < 3) {
            return false;
        }

        if (strlen($username) > 17) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!ctype_alnum($username)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        if (!$this->isValidUsername($username)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (strlen($password) < 3) {
            return false;
        }

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        $permissions = $this->get_user_permissions($username);

        if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $row['tfaSwitch'] == "Off") {

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];
            $_SESSION['userRoleID'] = $row['userRoleID'];
            $_SESSION['permissions'] = $permissions;


            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }
    

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function check_users_permissions($permissionID, $permissionName)
    {
        
        foreach ($_SESSION['permissions'] as $permissions) {
            if (isset($permissions['permissionID']) && isset($permissions['permissionName']) && $permissions['permissionID'] === $permissionID && $permissions['permissionName'] === $permissionName) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Here is how i call my `check_users_permissions` function:**

```
if ($user->check_users_permissions(1, "Access users")) { 
    echo "Y";   
}
```

**Here is what stored `$_SESSION['permissions']` when user login:**

Array ( [loggedin] => 1 [username] => admin [userID] => 2 [userRoleID] => 1 [permissions] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [roleID] => 1 [0] => 1 [permissionID] => 1 [1] => 1 [permissionName] => Access users [2] => Access users ) [1] => Array ( [roleID] => 1 [0] => 1 [permissionID] => 2 [1] => 2 [permissionName] => Create new users [2] => Create new users ) [2] => Array ( [roleID] => 1 [0] => 1 [permissionID] => 3 [1] => 3 [permissionName] => Update users [2] => Update users ) [3] => Array ( [roleID] => 1 [0] => 1 [permissionID] => 4 [1] => 4 [permissionName] => Delete users [2] => Delete users ) ) )

Comment: Most probably because your localhost environment is configured differently than the actual live server. I would check the php version first. Then if you have access to the live server, I'll check the web server log to see if any errors are logged. It also depends how php runs on the live server; if it runs as an apache dso module, or as fcgi or as suphp or using php-fpm etc. So it's hard to answer your question only with the provided information

Comment: In logs I didn't see any errors. PHP versions are same also but I haven't checked these modules and I don't know exactly what to try with them.

Comment: It depens on the live server configuration. There might be a permission error as in the user running the php script might not have the necessary permissions to actually write the session files on the live server's default path for php session files which is usually ```/var/lib/php/session```.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to work with this. Hope it works.